# Using custom inputSplit and/or recordReader classes for reading JSON

Tags: java, json, hadoop

In my hadoop class they are wanting us to learn how to write/configure custom input format classes to handle data that isn't simply one record per line (like TextInputFormat).

The data is JSON data from the Twitter API, so it is basically a list of small JSON objects each representing tweets.

```
[
    {
        "text":"tweet string",
        ...more...
    },
    {
        ....
    },
]
```

The lab spec suggests focusing on writing a custom recordReader class that manually parses JSON in the given InputSplit, using something like a stack to keep track of opening/closing braces. Frankly this seems idiotic to me, I should not have to reinvent the wheel of parsing JSON... that's the advantage to using a standard data format.

Instead I was hoping to come up with a better solution using an existing JSON parser like json-simple. It seems I should be able to make a custom InputSplit class that splits the list of JSON objects into smaller sublists, and then the custom recordReader would also use the JSON parser to get each JSON object individually.

Is this a proper approach? Should I be customizing an InputSplit? Is there a better way to make a large JSON text consumable by a Hadoop MapReduce job?

Comment: Check this: http://java.dzone.com/articles/hadoop-practice